# Taking max of one column for multiple rows in R

Tags: r, datatable, max, grouping

I have 3 columns of xyz data. The points are regulary spaced in x and y direction. I would like to find out the max value of z for each step of x.
I was able to do this for one "x" value which I specifically assigned, but as there are a lot more, I created a vector *(vecx)* by using function *unique()* with all possible values inside. Unfortunately I was not able to assign it correctly, as only the value that matches the overall max value of z was picked (which is logical). I am not sure if there is a easy solution by just using a grouping funktion for the x values instead of my way of using a vector?

```
xyzmax <- xyz[x %in%vecx ][which.max(z)]
```

This is a short preview of the data(x,y and z are labels of the columns in xyz:

> ```
>      x        y    z
> ```
>
> 1. 1810.0 5932.200 4767
> 2. 1810.0 5982.108 4746
> 3. 1810.0 6032.015 4717
> 4. 1856.5 5483.031 4736
> 5. 1856.5 5532.938 4738
> 6. 1856.5 5582.846 4746
> 7. 1856.5 5632.754 4742
> 8. 1856.5 5682.662 4752
> 9. 1856.5 5732.569 4756

and this is what it should look like, after running the code:

> ```
>          x        y       z
> ```
>
> 1. **1810.0** 5932.200 **4767**
> 2. **1856.5** 5732.569 **4756**

As there are hundreds of x values and the values are changing with resolution of the point grid. That is why I am not keen to enter them by hand or create tables for single values which is done in similar questions. I just started to work  with R and would be thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: Use `aggregate` with `max`

Answer (score 2):

`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .SD[which.max(z)], by = x]

#         x        y    z
# 1: 1810.0 5932.200 4767
# 2: 1856.5 5732.569 4756
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  slice(which.max(z))
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread("
   x        y    z
1810.0 5932.200 4767
1810.0 5982.108 4746
1810.0 6032.015 4717
1856.5 5483.031 4736
1856.5 5532.938 4738
1856.5 5582.846 4746
1856.5 5632.754 4742
1856.5 5682.662 4752
1856.5 5732.569 4756
")
```

Comment: Or using `ave` `df[with(df, ave(z, x, FUN = max) == z),]`